# The parameter type is not valid for a function of this linkage type

Tags: c, built-in, xlc, altivec

I'm working on AIX with IBM's XL C compiler. I'm catching a compile error and I'm not sure how to proceed:

```
$ xlc -g3 -O0 -qarch=pwr8 -qaltivec fips197-p8.c -o fips197-p8.exe
"fips197-p8.c", line 59.16: 1506-754 (W) The parameter type is not valid for a function of this linkage type.
```

The relevant source code is shown below. The complete source code is available at [`fips197-p8.c`](https://github.com/noloader/AES-Power8). The source code is a test driver for Power 8 `__cipher` and `__vcipherlast`. It has a main and a few C functions. Effectively is a minimal complete working example for Power 8 AES.

```c
$ cat -n fips197-p8.c
...

11  #if defined(__xlc__) || defined(__xlC__)
12  // #include <builtins.h>
13  #include <altivec.h>
14  typedef vector unsigned char uint8x16_p8;
15  typedef vector unsigned int uint64x2_p8;
16  #else
17  #include <altivec.h>
18  typedef vector unsigned char uint8x16_p8;
19  typedef vector unsigned long long uint64x2_p8;
20  #endif
...

52  uint8x16_p8 Load8x16(const uint8_t src[16])
53  {
54  #if defined(__xlc__) || defined(__xlC__)
55          /* IBM XL C/C++ compiler */
56  # if defined(__LITTLE_ENDIAN__)
57          return vec_xl_be(0, src);
58  # else
59          return vec_xl(0, src);
60  # endif
61  #else
62          /* GCC, Clang, etc */
63
64  #endif
65  }
```

The compiler version is shown below. We don't control the compiler, so this is what we have:

```
$ xlc -qversion
IBM XL C/C++ for AIX, V13.1.3 (5725-C72, 5765-J07)
Version: 13.01.0003.0000
```

`vec_xl` is fine on a little-endian. `vec_xl` for big-endian is giving us the trouble.

What is the problem, and how do I fix it?

Comment: AIX + IBM? You have my sympathy

Comment: however, this is difficult to reproduce without an AIX. IBM isn't particular helpful here.

Comment: from the docs: "The order of elements in the function result is big endian when -qaltivec=be is in effect. Otherwise, the order is little endian." You didn't set `=be`, isn't that an issue?

Comment: Does it work better if you cast `src` into `const unsigned char*`?

Comment: @ikegami  - I forgot to mention... I tried the cast.

Comment: I may have an idea: maybe this thing works in place and `const uint8_t src[16]` should be `uint8_t src[16]`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - thanks, the last suggestion worked around it. Its sounds like a compiler bug. You should probably answer.

Comment: @jww: wow, got me a `xlc` badge, gold in 999 :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - Congrats. I've got one more related question, then I can move onto my next task and leave the Power 8 and XL C/C++ folks alone. Also see [What is the purpose of “bl <next instruction>”?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/46128075/608639)

Comment: @jww: you're blessed with the worst technologies: powerpc & AIX & IBM... I know very little powerpc stuff, but I'll check your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So a little guesswork (confirmed by OP comments since it works) led me to think that this cryptic & obscure "The parameter type is not valid for a function of this linkage type." message (google first match is this question !) could be a *qualifier* issue.

Since your contract is

```
uint8x16_p8 Load8x16(const uint8_t src[16])
```

it is possible that, given the options & the current endianness, the compiler/prototype believes that `vec_xl_be` expects a *non-const* parameter as `src`.

So passing a `const` violates the contract (and that's the nicest way `xlc` could find to notifu you)

So either change to

```
uint8x16_p8 Load8x16(uint8_t src[16])
```

(with the risk of dropping constant constraints for all callers)

or drop the `const` by a non-const cast (like we do when the prototype lacks `const`, but the data is in fact not modified in the function):

```
vec_xl_be(0,(uint8_t*)src);
```

Comment: Thanks. I also found [IV91684: PARAMETER TYPE ERROR FOR VECTOR BUILT-INS VEC_CMPGE AND VEC_CMPLE](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IV91684). I guess that's what the hotfix is about. I don't work with XL C/C++ compiler enough to connect the dots.

Comment: good find. But it seems to me that it's a kind of "same symptom different causes". That reminds us that `gcc` treats us very well :)

Comment: Thanks for raising this issue, and sorry for the misleading diagnostic. The compiler is trying to save you a bad situation where you might pass a const argument into a non-const interface, but the error message could be improved.

Comment: @trudeaun: that, or it shouldn't raise it in the first place, or the prototype is brolen given the compilation switches. Anyway, I cannot test that since I don't have the code or the AIX machine... Glad that it worked out :)